# Getting not valid cursor error on jpa oracle sql developer

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jpa, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to update a field on a table using this JAVA method:

```
    @Query(value="UPDATE tableExample "
        + "SET tableExample.DTFINE = sysdate " 
        + "WHERE tableExample.prv = :idPrv AND tableExample.DTFINE IS NULL", nativeQuery=true)
        public void updateDtFine( Long idPrv);
```

But for some reason, I'm getting this error:

```
     ORA-01002: cursore non valido
     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:494)
     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:446)
     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1054)
     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:623)
     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:252)
     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:612)
     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:226)
     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.fetch(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1023)
     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.fetchMoreRows(OracleStatement.java:3353)
     at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.fetchMoreRows(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:736)
     at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.absoluteInternal(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:692)
     at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.next(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:406)
     at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.ResultSet_oracle_jdbc_driver_ForwardOnlyResultSet.next(Unknown Source)
     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:1004)
     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:964)
     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2815)
     ... 88 more
     Caused by: Error : 1002, Position : 0, Sql = UPDATE tableExample SET 
     tableExample.DTFINE = sysdate WHERE tableExample.prv = :1  AND tableExample.DTFINE 
     IS NULL, OriginalSql = UPDATE tableExample SET tableExample.DTFINE = sysdate WHERE 
     tableExample.prv = ? AND tableExample.DTFINE IS NULL, Error Msg = ORA-01002: 
     cursore non valido
```

I really don't understand why it's not working. I even tried the same update query directly on oracle sql developer

```
   UPDATE tableExample SET tableExample.DTFINE = sysdate WHERE tableExample.prv = 18 
   AND tableExample.DTFINE IS NULL
```

and it works with no errors.
Is there something i'm missing? And what exactly means "not valid cursor"?

Comment: "Not valid cursor" implies that your SQL is somehow invalid. How is the value of `:idPrv` (or `:1`) set? Is it possible that it is either not being set, or is being set to an invalid value?

Comment: Have you marked this using the @Modifying annotation? It executes the query as a select query without it.

Comment: @Chris i tried putting the Modifying annotation on the updateDtFine declaration, but it returns 
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Executing an update/delete query; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query

I never needed to put it on any other save or delete query (i'm using jpaRepository interface and Repository annotation)

Comment: Save and some other repo operations might get automatically put in a transaction context by spring, but everything needs a transaction or it doesn't get committed to the database. If you don't have one, they don't really execute - JPA operations are lazily done when the transaction is flushed or committed.

Comment: I've also found out that it executes the update in the db, but it then throws an error anyway, like it tries to update in loop

Comment: since i'm using an autowired interface with @Repository annotation, I don't have an implementation of the repository, nor am i explicitly using an EntityManager.
I have many other abstract save and delete methods that never caused me such an error. I think Modifying is needed only in case I had a RepositoryImpl class or something similar...

Comment: By now, I've just skipped the exception, since I checked the db and seen that the rows get updated anyway. I've put a catch that does nothing and tested it... I don't care if it causes an exception as long as it updates the rows I need.